# Laravel 5.2 enums with database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table called role with 5 columns (id,name,role,created_At,update_at).
I need to create a enum ADMINISTRATOR => 'Adinistrador',EMPLOYEE=>'Colaborador'in the databse. And i need access to verifie if is admin, my though is put the query smeting like this:
table->role(ADMINISTRATOR);

Is a beter way to do enums with database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using enums in db table has one big disadvantage: if you need to add a new value you have to alter the table. If your table has a lot of rows it can be quite time consuming operation. I personally prefer to use tinyint field as foreign key to table that consists of two fields: id, description of the value.

**Mysql**
Column `role` in your table will store int values 1, 2, 3, 4.
Table `roles` will store rows in a way like: `(1, ADMINISTRATOR), (2, User)` and so on.

**Laravel**

```
define('ADMINISTRATOR', 1);
define('User', 2);

table->role(ADMINISTRATOR); // search for ADMINISTRATOR
```

Comment: in this case the result is id => ADMINISTRATOR description=>"Administrador"? how i invoke the method to check if is admin or EMPLOYEE?

Comment: the column role store the values and the other column **description** stores the ADMINISTRATOR, EMPLOYEE, but i needto store portogueses descripion

Comment: You will need to create two tables: your table where column role stores id and table roles with id, description. Your table will have fk to roles. @FabioSantos

Comment: thanks´for your help. I will try and send somo feedback